# Coldfusion Amazon S3 support for file upload, does it connect to a specific IP?

Tags: coldfusion, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use S3 as an off site file location for a database backup. On my home dev machine this works just fine, I just do a dump out from mySQL and then

```
<cffile action = "copy"
source = "#backupPath##filename#"
destination = "s3://myID:myKey@myBucket/#filename#">
```

and all is good. However, the production server at work is behind a router/firewall controlled/managed by a 3rd party. I read somewhere that S3 needs port 843 open to work (and then lost that reference) but does the CF built in function connect to a particular IP at amazon so I could ask for that port open for just that IP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that you found some answers via comments on [Ray Camden's blog post about the S3 functionality](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2010/7/15/CF901-Guide-to-Amazon-S3-support-in-ColdFusion-901#c92BFD007-0BED-0CAC-859A19390F4212DD), with information contributed by [Steven Erat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151146/steven-erat), but for the sake of completeness here on Stack Overflow and for others who may find this question, here is that information:

By default, all communication from your CF server and S3 is done over HTTPS on port 443. There is a Java system property (`s3service.https-only`), which defaults to true, and will do the communication over http and not over https if you set it to false. Sorry, I don't know how you might change it, unless maybe as a JVM argument.

The IP of any given bucket could be different (and possibly change over time), so you can't necessarily get by on opening a port for a single IP -- but luckily you shouldn't have to since it's all done over SSL/443.

What does use port 843 is the [Amazon S3 console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/), an optional flash-based web interface for managing your bucket(s).